# How to use `hostname` in main.cnf postfix

Tags: shell, email, ubuntu, scripting, postfix-mta

hope you can help.

I have 40 odd servers to install postfix on, I've taken the necessary files from a working server and scripted it to install and copying the files in to place, the issue I'm having is that i can't use **`hostname`** for these setings as **postmap** fails, see below

**myhostname = `hostname`
mydestination = `hostname`, localhost.`hostname`**

Thanks
**postmap: warning: valid_hostname: invalid character 96(decimal): `hostname`
postmap: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: `hostname`**

Answer (score 0):

The installation of postfix takes care of the main.cf, only needed to copy sasl & canonical files and run postmap. DOH